# How to get and display inform from Apex with Javascript Controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I built an application with Lightning Experience. In my custom apex controller, I have a method named `getParam`.

```
public class compController {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<ObjectParent> getParam (Id master) {
    List<ObjectParent__c> objList = [SELECT ID, Name, (SELECT ID, textField1__c, checkBox1__c FROM Child__r] FROM ObjectParent WHERE MasterID__c =: master];
    return objList;
  }
}
```

Lightning Component

```
    <aura:component>
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
          <aura:attribute name="listObjectParent" type="ObjectParent" />
          <aura:attribute name="master" type="String" default="1231242112341" /> 
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.listObjectParent}" var="objdata" 
                   indexVar="index">
                <p>{!objdata.checkBox1__c}</p>
                <p>{!objdata.textField1__c}</p>
             </aura:iteration>
  </aura:component>
```

JS Client Side Controller

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getParam");
        var master = component.get("v.master");
        action.setParams({"master" : master});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
                var listObjectParent = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.listObjectParent", listObjectParent);
            }else{
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });    
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

I need to initialize this with js client side controller at the component. I understand the output is a list in the list, which looks like:

1. parent ID, parent name, `["ID","1234" ,"textField1__c", "xx1", "checkBox1", "true"]`
2. parent ID, parent name, `["ID","3456" ,"textField1__c", "xx2", "checkBox1", "false"]`

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I updated post. I think - my JS controller is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this in markup you can use `aura:iteration` to iterate through it a get the values.

Let's say the aura attribute in client side is `objParentdata`:

```
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.objParentdata}" var="objdata" indexVar="index">
    <p>{!objdata.checkBox1}</p>
    <p>{!objdata.textField1__c}</p>
  </aura:iteration>
```

Comment: I updated post. I know that I should use aura iteration but I think - i doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you do a console.log(JSON.stringify(listObjectParent)) of  var listObjectParent.I think the way you are accessing variables must be where the issue is

Comment: So, I get correct info but I don't know how I should iterate for this. 

[{"Id":"a0A46000001ycBzEAI","Name":"imię?","Child__r":[{"Question__c":"a0A46123401ycBzEAI","Id":"a0B46123400X5ZGEA0","checkBox1__c":true,"textField1__c":"xd1"},{"Question__c":"a0A46123401ycBzEAI","Id":"a0B46123400X5ZCEA0","checkBox1__c":false,"textField1__c":"xd2"},{"Question__c":"a0A46123401ycBzEAI","Id":"a0B46123400X5ZLEA0","checkBox1__c":true,"textField1__c":"xd3"}]}]

Comment: <aura:iteration items="{!v.listObjectParent}" var="objdata" indexVar="index">
             <p>{!objdata.Name}</p>
 <aura:iteration items="{!objdata.Child__r}" var="childqdata" indexVar="index1">
      <p>{!childqdata.checkBox1__c}</p>
     </aura:iteration>    
 </aura:iteration>      
</aura:component> try this out

Comment: you have a child list inside a parent so you need an aura iteration inside another

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are getting value from Apex is a list and you are using an object attribute instead of list object:

```
<aura:attribute name="listObjectParent" type="ObjectParent" />
```

Should be:

```
<aura:attribute name="listObjectParent" type="ObjectParent[]" />
```

Comment: I correct this earlier.

Comment: Ohh, you forgot to update in the question.